# Codeigniter redirect not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my class constructor the redirect function working properly

```
 public function __construct(){

  parent::__construct();
  $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
  if( $session_data['type']!='admin' ){
  //this redirect working properly
  redirect('login');
  }
    $this->load->model('functions');
    $this->load->model('user');
}
```

But inside my one of other function in same class, that not working

```
public function logout(){
        $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        //this redirect not working
        redirect('login');
    }
```

I tried out several ways, but could not make it work.
In my autoload I have loaded url helper properly. 
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form'); So whats wrong with this.

Comment: can you show your full code

Comment: if you are using windows try `redirect('login', 'refresh');`

Comment: Inside my other controllers also redirect() function not works

Comment: it should refer to that controller where login() function is used.

Comment: show me that controller where login() is used @Janaka

Comment: I added the login.php page too, to the above url @NanaPartykar

Comment: I didn't asked you to add. You have one more controller other than Admin controller. In that controller, you have login() or index(). I want that controller

Comment: I redirected it to other location, but it also not works, redirect('car'); I think it is some issue with redirect function of Codeignitor

Comment: I have index() in my login.php @NanaPartykar

Comment: why it will not work, @NanaPartykar

Comment: give redirect('/login/index');

Comment: in login.php what controller name using ?

Comment: I did that way too, but not ok.

Comment: login.php, controller name is Login

Comment: in Login controller, any function there to redirect to login page.

Comment: No, actually I can do that using $this->load->view('login_view'); in my redirect location only for this case, but in other functions also redirect not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the problem is there are some spaces after the PHP end tag in my user model I used in this controller. So I removed those spaces then redirect function worked properly. Herewith I've attached a screenshot got from Sublime editor. Thanks everyone who tried for this.[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

First option,

```
redirect('login', 'refresh');
```

Second option,

```
redirect('login');
exit;
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Tnx and my full code is here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wSgHIEg0y-TlRFtQWQHwKL4NrqoyIr2nbYF3fWdRW8w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am using ci version 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
redirect(base_url().'login');
```

Use **base_url()** brefore controller name '**login**'

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use base_url() functions with your controller name and function name